# Bulk insert operation are going too slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, innodb

Here is the Structure of my 'venprices' table.

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| conid | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rate  | double      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| venid | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

JAVA Code :

```
new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;
                XSSFSheet mySheet = null;
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = null;
                String venid = null, errorlog = null;
                int code;
                double rate;
                int rows, maxcount;
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                Connection con;
                ProgressMonitor pm;
                try {
                    myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(jTextField1.getText())));
                    mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
                    rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();
                    rowIterator.next();
                    venid = jComboBox1.getItemAt(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
                    con = Mycon.getConnection();
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM venprices WHERE venid = ?");
                    ps.setString(1, venid);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.clearBatch();    
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into venprices values (?,?,?)");
                } catch(Exception ioe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe.getMessage());
                }
                    rows = 1;maxcount = mySheet.getLastRowNum();
                    // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
                    while (rowIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        try{
                            Row row = rowIterator.next();
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                            code = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            cell = cellIterator.next();
                            rate = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            ps.setInt(1,code);
                            ps.setDouble(2,rate);
                            ps.setString(3, venid);
                            ps.addBatch();
                            rows++;
                        }catch(Exception e){errorlog = errorlog + "\n" +rows+ e.getMessage();}
                    }
                    try{
                        System.gc();
                        ps.executeBatch();
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    if(errorlog == null)
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Import Successful. " + rows + " Records Imported.");
                    else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Log :\n"+errorlog);
            }
        }.start();
```

The user is expected to insert around 50,000 records in a single shot with an Excel File. But the query takes around 6-7 minutes.
Can anyone please help me in reducing the insert operation time or tell me some tweaks in the insert query?
Thanks in Advance!

Edit 1:
As Requested, Here is the result of `show create table venprices`

```
mysql> show create table venprices;
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| venprices | CREATE TABLE `venprices` (
  `conid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `venid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`conid`,`venid`),
  KEY `vepr` (`conid`,`rate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `describe` is never as good as `show create table venprices`

Comment: Sorry I din't get you.

Comment: can you type in `show create table venprices` , hit Enter, get results, paste at top with an [edit]

Comment: Done. Please check the edits.

Comment: The fastest way this data comes in is with a `load data infile` from mysql. It means you have a csv file ideally on your server. That could cut down 50k individual calls to conceivably well under a minute. Maybe 30 seconds

Comment: On a side note, never use floating-point types for storing money, or you might be in a world of trouble. DECIMAL is so much better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Java syntax, but add a MySQL `START TRANSACTION` (`BEGIN`) at the beginning of your code.  And add `COMMIT` to the end.

Why?

50K rows inserted in 6-7 minutes smells very much like inserting each row in its own transaction (a la `autocommit=ON`).  This is slow because of all the transactional activity on the disk.

By turning the 50K transactions into 1 transaction, you will have a lot less I/O, hence it will run faster.

Secondly...  By turning the 50K 1-row `INSERTs` into 50 1000-row `INSERTs`, you can get another 10x speedup.  This is because of avoiding most of the roundtrip time between client and server and most of the parsing time.  (Again, I don't know if Java has a special class to facilitate such; it might.)

These two changes will *perhaps* be competitive with Drew's `LOAD_DATA INFILE` approach.